# Why my Teradata stored procedure is not running

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata, dynamic-sql, teradata-sql-assistant

REPLACE PROCEDURE Dynamic_Select()
BEGIN
DECLARE stmt VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE result1 VARCHAR(50);

set stmt = 'SELECT count(*) into FROM table_name';

EXECUTE  immediate stmt into result1;
END;

Error Message:
SPL1027:E(L8), Missing/Invalid SQL statement'E(3707):Syntax error, expected something like ';' between the word 'stmt' and the 'into' keyword.'.

Please help me on this. I am not getting how to take the count(*)  of my table into the result1 variable.

Please help me on this. I am not getting how to take the count(*)  of my table into the result1 variable.

Comment: That syntax is not even close to valid.  `INSERT INTO <target> select count(*) from <source>`. That's assuming your target table only has one column.

Comment: Havng re-read, what are you trying to actually do - insert into a table or into a variable?

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cannot return data. Use a dynamic cursor for that - DECLARE the cursor for a "statement" name, PREPARE that statement name from the SQL text, OPEN the cursor, FETCH the results. Or if the statement is always fixed, you can use SELECT INTO  but you'll need the target variable name(s) between INTO and FROM.